# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wifi'

Tags: python, python-2.7, wifi, raspberry-pi3

I always get this error even though I already installed [wifi](https://wifi.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) a python library for scanning and connecting wireless networks.

Can someone tell me what should I do? Should I reformat my RPi?
A little help is much appreciated.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from __future__ import print_function

from wifi import Cell, Scheme

#get all cells from the air
ssids = [cell.ssid for cell in Cell.all('wlan0')]

schemes = list(Scheme.all())

for scheme in schemes:
ssid = scheme.options.get('wpa-ssid', scheme.options.get('wireless-essid'))
if ssid in ssids:
    print('Connecting to %' % ssid)
    scheme.activate()
    break
```

I just copied it somewhere to test if this code will run but still got the same error.

This is for my python console:

```
Python 3.7.3 (default, Apr  3 2019, 05:39:12) 
[GCC 8.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more 
information.
>>> import wifi
>>>
```

Comment: can you attach the example pls? you can also open a python console and just import module for testing purposes.

Comment: @ilidream i edited my question so i already attached the example above.

Comment: could you check 'import wifi' in your python console? I also need to get console output. I've installed this module and it works fine.

Comment: should i reformat my RPi?

Comment: yes, I think you have to do it